# How to overwrite Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm jusing an external JS plugin, which I initialised using this script:

```js
    (function(g,s,t,p,l,n){
        g["_gstpln"]={};
        (l=s.createElement(t)),(n=s.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]);
        l.async=1;l.src=p;n.parentNode.insertBefore(l,n);
    })(window,document,"script","https://cdn.guestplan.com/widget.js");
   
    _gstpln.accessKey = "cebd85865b61ba61961cc749c8ca02e43cad6535";
    _gstpln.color = "#000000";
    _gstpln.showFab = false;
```

When listening to its event handlers, I can see it uses the function `_gstpln.openWidget()` & `_gstpln.closeWidget()` on specific buttons. I want to tweak this function a little bit, so I tried to override it in the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   window._gstpln.closeWidget = function() {...}

   /* also tried it without `window.` */
});
```

But that doesn't work, I also tried to add `_gstpln.closeWidget = function() {...}` at the end of the initialization script. Didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: That would (probably) work **if** `_gstpln` were an old-fashioned global. If you remove the `window.` part, it would (probably) work **if** `_gstpln` were any kind of global. But most likely, it isn't. Instead, it's probably defined within a closure somewhere, and if that's the case, you *can't* overwrite it. (The "probably" part is that it's possible to create a property on an object that you can't write to.)

Comment: What exactly does "that doesn't work" mean? Are errors reported? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: @Pointy nothing means: when console logging `window._gstpln.closeWidget` I get the original function back, instead of the modified version.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder With or without `window.`, it's not working. There should be a way, because I've done it before with the exact same function but I lost the code due to it being overwritten through FTP.

Comment: @hans - There may well be a way, but it's impossible for us to tell you what it is with just the information in the question. You'll have to look at the plugin implementation and figure out where that function is assigned, and whether you have access to it in order to assign to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added some more information!

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is run as soon as the DOM is done loading, but the plugin's code doesn't assign to `closeWidget` until the `https://cdn.guestplan.com/widget.js` file is downloaded and executed, you have a race condition going on. It's a race I think your code will very likely win, but "winning" means you assign to `window._gstpln.closeWidget` *before* the plugin does, so your assignment is overwritten by theirs.

**If you an possibly achieve your purpose another way, I strongly recommend doing so. Monkey-patching a plugin like this is asking for trouble.**

So how do we handle the possibility that your code gets there first? I can think of a couple of ways:

1. By using an accessor property.
2. By polling, checking `window._gstpln.closeWidget` until we see that it has a value, then overwriting the value.

The accessor property looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let original = window._gstpln.closeWidget;
    const replacement = function() {
        // ...you can use `original` here if you need to call the
        // original implementation; presumably if `closeWidget`
        // is being called, `openWidget` has been called and so
        // the `widget.js` script has loaded...
    };
    Object.defineProperty(window._gstpln, "closeWidget", {
        get() {
            return replacement;
        },
        set(fn) {
            original = fn;
        },
    });
});
```

How that works:

1. We grab the original value of `closeWidget` when your code runs, in case the other script has already run and filled it in.
2. We replace it with an accessor property:

   - When the property value is read, the `get` function is called and returns your replacement function.
   - When the property value is *written*, presumably that's because your code ran before the `widget.js` script finished loading, and so this is that script assigning to `window._gstpln.closeWidget`. So that's the "original" version of the function, which we tuck away into the `original` variable we set up earlier.

So in theory, at that point, your code will always be run when `closeWidget` is run, and because there's a setter, we'll get the original function (if you need it) even if your code runs first.

Even if you don't need the original function, you probably don't want to make `closeWidget` read-only, because parts (at least) of `widget.js` are in strict mode, and assigning to read-only properties in strict mode throws an error, which would interrupt the `widget.js` script and probably make things not work.

Alternatively, we could make that a bit smarter by only making it an accessor if the other code didn't get there first, and redefining the property on the first `set` if it did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let original = window._gstpln.closeWidget;
    const replacement = function() {
        // ...you can use `original` here if you need to call the
        // original implementation; presumably if `closeWidget`
        // is being called, `openWidget` has been called and so
        // the `widget.js` script has loaded...
    };
    if (original) {
        // The `widget.js` code got there first, the simple way should work
        // Note: This creates a read-only property, so if `widget.js` assigns
        // to it a second time, it'll (possibly) throw an error
        Object.defineProperty(window._gstpln, "closeWidget", {
            value: replacement,
        });
    } else {
        // We got there first, use an accessor that redefines on `set`
        Object.defineProperty(window._gstpln, "closeWidget", {
            get() {
                return replacement;
            },
            set(fn) {
                original = fn;
                Object.defineProperty(window._gstpln, "closeWidget", {
                    value: replacement,
                });
            },
            configurable: true, // <== So that we can change it above
        });
    }
});
```

The polling version looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let timeout = Date.now() + 60000; // 60 second timeout
    check();
    function check() {
        let original = window._gstpln.closeWidget;
        if (!original) {
            if (Date.now() > timeout) {
                // Give up!
            } else {
                setTimeout(check, 50); // 50ms or whatever
            }
            return;
        }
        window._gstpln.closeWidget = function() {
            // ...you can use `original` here if you need it...
        };
    }
});
```

**Neither of these is a good idea.** But if you can't avoid it, one or the other (possibly with some tweaking) should work.